# How can we run specific test cases automatically based on the development scenarios fix? Selenium+java+cucumber

Tags: selenium, gradle, automated-tests, bdd, cucumber-java

Suppose test automation suite has 100 test cases and development has done one fix that has impact on only 10 test cases. When the fix is done by development, instead of running 100 test cases through automation how to run just impacted 10 test cases automatically without any manual selection of testcases to run(I am using selenium,java,cucumber BDD,gradle)

Comment: The main use of test automation is to cover regression and you want to avoid that ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this would be to use [Tags](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tags) to tag each automated test with the functionality that it covers.

```
@billing @bicker @annoy
Feature: Verify billing
```

Some tests may have multiple tags depending on what functionality it touches. Once dev pushes a new build, they let you know what features they touched and you kick off a run filtered down to only the tags that dev said they touched, e.g. using maven

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@smoke and @fast"
```

Having said that... you should not ignore PDHide's comment. What if dev only *thinks* they touched the one feature but accidentally broke other areas? QA has jobs because devs aren't perfect. That's not an insult or saying they are sloppy or stupid but applications are complicated. Some applications are REALLY complicated. Even the best devs make mistakes.

Having said that and that... maybe the automation run you are asking about is run as a quick sanity check. You run only the tests tagged with X feature and then once that completes you have some really quick feedback, then you run the full suite.

With only 100 tests, I would look at ways to run tests in parallel on multiple VMs. Unless your tests are 10 mins each (man I hope they aren't or that's a whole other issue), you should be able to complete a full suite in less than an 30 mins easily. At work, one of our suites has ~400 tests in it that probably average ~2 mins per test. We have our suite hooked up to 10 VMs, each of which can run 4 browsers (that's 40 concurrent browsers). That 400 test run that should take about 800 minutes (13+ hours) takes less than 30 mins.